# find the number of ways of selecting 9 balls from 6 red balls 5 white balls and 5 blue balls if each selection contains 3 balls of each colour.

Tags: combinatorics

The question in my book has been solved this way
$\binom{6}{3}\binom{5}{3}\binom{5}{3}$ but I think that there should only be one way of this combination because no matter how we select 3 balls from each colour they should be considered the same thing. In this question should the balls of same colour be considered as distinct objects?

Comment: Within each color, balls are considered indistinguishable.  That is how you should treat it.  The answer is correct also

Comment: @satishramanathan So is the answer 1 combination or something else?

Comment: The answer given assumes that the 6 red balls are distinguishable... think of them as being numbered but also red.  Similarly for the remaining balls.

Comment: Yes, apparently the balls of the same colour are distinguishable by some property...maybe size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you consider balls of the same colour to be distinguishable or not.   The answer given does not do so, and if you are counting to measure probabilities, or such, there are reasons not to do so, even if an observer cannot tell them apart.

There are ${^6\mathrm C_3} \times {^5\mathrm C_3} \times {^5\mathrm C_3}$ ways to select 3 distinct balls of each colour.

Trivially, there is but $1$ way to select 3 indistinguishable balls of each colour.

Answer (score 1):

If you treat the balls within each color as the same, then there may be a problem: the number of choosing three blue balls from $5$ is $1$; from $6$ there is $1$; from $7$ there is $1$, and so on. The number of balls of a color will be meaningless.

I guess your teacher expects you to use the ${n\choose k}$ model in this question. Before answering this kind of questions, you need to be familiar with the rules of the game.